# Website with trading and Ripple wallet?

Tags: wallet, exchanges, ripple

I plan to start crypto trading with Ripple and other coins.

What litebit.eu type of site you recommend which support Ripple and many other coins and has wallet for Ripple too? If i use litebit i need to have gatehub too and i would like to have only one website.

It's hard to find such site because that would require to create account to all of these sites. :-(

That's why i ask here if anybody knows such site.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know Poloniex and Bittrex is good, i use Poloniex my self to trade currencies.. http://coinmarketlist.com/ <-- maybe there you find some other exchange platforms.. there are lot of platforms out there.

About wallet i don't know :(

Answer (score 1):

Exchanges that are trading Ripple should at least have wallet support and allow you to trade XRP. Listing can be found at https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/ripple/trading_exchanges#panel

Other than that best to run your own wallet and control your private keys to store large XRPs